# "Земля круглая" — прописная или строчная?

Tags: прописная-строчная

В поговорке "Земля круглая", если она употребляется в прямой речи в середине предложения, нужно ли писать слово "Земля" с прописной?

Егорушка воскликнул:
— Недаром говорят, что [зЗ]емля круглая!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Егорушка воскликнул:
— Недаром говорят, что **земля круглая!**

С прописной буквы "Земля" пишется **в специальной литературе**, когда речь идет о космическом теле. В обычных текстах нужно писать со строчной буквы, если даже говорится о том, что земля круглая. Интересно отметить, что написание с прописной буквы также встречается, но оно не кажется обоснованным.

Примеры:

Но не зря говорится, что **земля круглая!** [Виктор Астафьев. Зрячий посох (1978-1982)]

И вот, сейчас снова встретились! Тесен мир, **земля круглая!** Пошли оживленные расспросы. [Л. К. Бронтман. Дневники и письма (1943-1946)]

Птицы летят на места гнездования будто бы по прямой линии, но сама **земля круглая**, и пока они с экватора на север долетят, линия полета их загибается,… [М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1926)]

Answer (score 1):

Слово "Земля" пишется с большой буквы когда употребляется в качестве астрономического названия. В остальных случаях пишется с маленькой.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае, мне кажется, под "Землёй" имеется в виду планета. Поэтому правильно **с большой буквы.**

Comment: А если Егорушке только поговорка известна? :)

Comment: То есть Егорушке самому это надо написать? :)

Comment: Надо его понимание отображать: он может иметь в виду совсем не планету Земля (мог не слышать о планетах, если маленький), а плоскую как блин землю круглой формы.

Comment: Тоже верно... Не знаю тогда, выходит, правильный ответ, что большая или маленькая буква определяется его пониманием и знаниями.))